# how to sanitizing $_POST with the correct way?

Tags: security, validation, sanitization, escaping

I am trying to sanitize and validate and escape this code?

```
    $positions = $_POST['positions'];

    foreach ($positions as $key => $position) {
      $id = sanitize_text_field($position[0]);
      $one = sanitize_text_field($position[1]);
      $two = sanitize_text_field($position[2]);
      $three = sanitize_text_field($position[3]);
      $four = sanitize_text_field($position[4]);

      $result = $wpdb->update( $wpdb->prefix.'test_my_table',
      array('one'=>$one,'two'=>$two ,'three'=>$three, 'four' => $four),array( 'id' => $id ));
   }
```

also i am trying to sanitize this code but i don't know how anyone can help?

```
header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'].' 200 OK');
```

Comment: you don't escape until you output to the browser, never on input. Otherwise it's not possible to tell you how to sanitize the `positions` field without knowing information about its purpose, the HTML that is supposed to generate it, and what the value contains. Sanitising and making a value safe depends enormously on the context, can you add context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of looping through the array, use this:

```
map_deep( $form_data, 'sanitize_text_field' );
```

(see the User Notes in the function doc: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/sanitize_text_field/ )

The docs state that

```
Checks for invalid UTF-8,
Converts single < characters to entities
Strips all tags
Removes line breaks, tabs, and extra whitespace
Strips percent-encoded characters
```

So you could also use the map_deep() process to sanitize $_POST.

But note also that the docs say:

> This function is not for protecting against SQL injection, so please
> don’t use it in your database queries. In most cases using
> https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/prepare/ with
> placeholders is best for database queries.

Comment: Thank you so much it was so useful, but can you please help me about this code `header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'].' 200 OK');` I'm working on plugin and wordpress they asked me to sanitize, validate, escape  the last cod but i didn't understand how to do it?!

Comment: Regarding the other part of your question, I have no idea what you (or the code) is attempting to do with that single line of code. More information (surrounding code) is needed to understand the context or intention of that part of the code. A HEADER is usually used to send a response to a request (often as part of other 'header' responses). It is not a request from a client, so there shouldn't be any need to sanitize it. But more context is needed; perhaps in a new question.